# Batch URL variable

Tags: url, batch-file, amazon-s3

i want to make a minecraft skin downloader in batch. So i want it to ask for a name, for example if i type skilande, to open a window with the url of the skin. If i type skilande, it will open a URL
s3.amazonaws.com/MinecraftSkins/**skilande**.png and if i type for example Tinn to open a URL s3.amazonaws.com/MinecraftSkins/**Tinn**.png
I don't know really how to do that and it will be very awesome if you could tell me how..

Is this possible? Thanks a lot.

Comment: check bitsadmin -> http://ss64.com/nt/bitsadmin.html or download some of the wget implementations for windows

Answer (score 0):

```
set /p "var=Enter Name: "
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe" "s3.amazonaws.com/MinecraftSkins/%var%.png"
```

(the last two lines should be on one line with a space between)

Comment: this will not download the picture directly.After that he/she will need to kill the internet explorer and to check internet explorer cache which can be not so easy.